# yocto-bsp command not found

Tags: linux, command, yocto

I'm playing around with yocto currently and want to create a specific BSP for a raspberry pi (learning exercise, so don't want to use the provided meta-rpi layer).

The manual is telling me to type the command "yocto-bsp help" but my system is saying that the command is not found.

I've tried it with a few versions of poky now (zeus currently).

I've done a find for any file name this and the system doesn't find anything. I've also tried sending the command after "source oe-init-build-env build_dir"

My system is able to find the command "yocto-check-layer"

Comment: Can you link to the manual that refers to yocto-bsp?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen here it is https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.2/bsp-guide/bsp-guide.html#creating-a-new-bsp-layer-using-the-yocto-bsp-script

Comment: @WorkerBee are you using yocto project release 1.2 (the documentation that you linked)? the zeus documentation on developing a bsp and the correct commands are [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/bsp-guide/bsp-guide.html#developing-a-board-support-package-bsp)

Answer (score 2):

yocto-bsp is no longer maintained. All relevant functionality should be available in other commands like `bitbake-layers`.

The procedure for creating a new BSP layer is documented in the [BSP Developer's Guide](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bsp-guide/bsp-guide.html#creating-a-new-bsp-layer-using-the-bitbake-layers-script).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Jussi, the Yocto manual needs to be updated. Any idea on how i can use the bitbake-layers to get to the same output? I don't mind reading any docs, just can't find them

Comment: For Yocto scripts, `--help` is enough most of the time to understand. By the way, there is no BSP layer creation script anymore, one way is to copy `meta-yocto-bsp` to make your own. See [commit](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/scripts?h=sumo&id=95d4f4ec1e512d612242695542f04cbd472f3463)

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:
`bitbake-layers create-layer <yourlayer>`